# ¿Es posible utilizar ImageDataGenerator para obtener unas imágenes de entrenamiento nivelados?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

Tengo un dataset previamente dividido (test,training) bastante desnivelado en numero de imágenes por etiqueta (el más grande es de 700 y el más pequeño de 30). Según entiendo con ImageDataGenerator podria generar nuevas imágenes según unas determinadas modificaciones de rotación, etc

Entonces he pensado que podría utilizarlo para generar más imágenes para las etiquetas de menor número de imágenes y de manera progresiva con el resto de etiquetas hasta conseguir aproximadamente una nivelación del numero de imágenes por etiqueta. Posteriormente realizaría el entrenamiento.

Me he estado rompiendo la cabeza para conseguir esa nivelación mediante varios bucles y transformaciones pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien porque creo que puede haber una manera más sencilla o simplemente me estoy equivocando de estrategia para conseguir un buen entrenamiento.

Answer (score 1):

**El problema que intentas atacar es clases desbalanceadas.** No creo que ImageDataGenerator resuelva la performance accuracy de tu test de la misma manera que si tu clases fueran balanceadas dado que ImageDataGenerator **introduce un leve ruido para mejorar la performance de tu modelo induciendo en el entrenamiento variaciones que de alguna manera aumentan el dominio de tu entrenamiento.** De todas formas creo que valdría la pena probarlo. Aquí te dejo una porción de código que hace exactamente lo que buscas:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img(<path a tu imagen.jpg como string>) 
x = img_to_array(img)  
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape) 
i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir='preview', save_prefix=<prefijo como str>, save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i > 20:
        break
```

Ahora intenta entrenar y clasificar comparando **el accuracy de la clase minoritaria.** para ver si mejoró.

Answer (score 1):

Agregando un poco más de información a la gran respuesta de @marmurar. Principalmente hay tres grandes formas de lidiar con bases de datos balanceadas (hay más trucos que voy a obviar por no ser los principales)

### 1. Conseguir más datos.

Tratar de conseguir más datos, en BB.DD de internet públicas, comprandolos, creandolos tú, etc.

### 2. Over Sampling y Under Sampling

Disgregando ligeramente con @marmurar, creo que la generación de nuevas imágenes (Over Sampling) a partir de las que tienes, es una técnica que ayuda a mejorar las redes neuronales, no solo puedes generar ruido, también como puedes ver en el mismo ejemplo que el ha puesto, girarlas, distorionarlas, cortarlas, hacer zoom, etc.

Under Sampling (quitar datos) también en tu caso es una buena técnica. Ya que la red neuronal trantando de reducir el error, tratará de clasificar todo como las muestras mayores y no se fijará en las muestras pequeñas (como en tu ejemplo 700 y 30). Por lo que de la clase/s que tengas una gran cantidad de datos, puedes quitar parte de ellos.

### 3. Establecer pesos para las clases

Con **Tensorlfow** el método `.fit()` tiene un hiperparámetro llamado `class_weight`. Esto te permite pasarle un diccionario con las clases y el peso que le quieres dar a cada clase. Te quedo un ejemplo reducido de como se hace:

```
import tensorlfow as tf

class_weight = {"cat": 0.75,
                "dog": 0.25}

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight)
```

En el ejemplo la clase *cat* tendría pocos datos y le daría un peso del 75%.

También puedes usar de `Scickit Learn` `compute_class_weight()` que te ayuda a calcular tus datos de forma balanceada, aquí un ejemplo:

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)

#Lo añadimos al modelo:
model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight=class_weights)
```